# Is the range of this plot correct using *ScalingFunctions -> "Log"*?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, discrete

I use DiscretePlot for a function $f$ and the result is

[image]

As I see, the range of the function includes negative values. Then, when I use *ScalingFunctions -> "Log"*, I obtain

[image]

Here, the negative range of the function is given by positive values. Is this true?

Comment: What version are you using? With v12.1.1, `Clear["\`*"]; DiscretePlot[10 (-1)^n, {n, 0, 10}, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]` correctly displays the result of `10` for only the even values of `n` since for odd values of `n` the `Log` is complex. Since your option is displayed in Red, it appears that it is not a valid option in your version. Was there some error message?

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks. No, there is not an error.  Then, what other commands I can use to get a correct result? The version is 10.4.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The red highlighting usually indicates that the option is unknown for the function. (I don't have V10.4 to check.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand it, you want to build a log-plot of a fuction taking negative values. In this case the `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"` option does not do the job. This can be done as follows. Compare

```
DiscretePlot[(-1)^n*n!, {n, 2, 7}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

with

```
DiscretePlot[Piecewise[{{Log[Max[(-1)^n*n!, 0]], (-1)^n*n! >= 
 0}, {-Log[-Min[(-1)^n*n!, 0]], (-1)^n*n! < 0}}], {n, 2, 7}]
```

[image]